# How to save the setting of font size in notepad++ as default?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using the `Solarized-light` theme in Notepad++. The default font of this theme is `consolas 10`. I've reset the size to 12 but every time I open Notepad++, the font size changes back to 10 again. It's really annoying to have to change it. Is there anyway to keep the font size as default?

Answer (score 54):

Well you can do it simply from the style settings.

Go to `Settings> Style Configurator`

and set the desired font size for the theme, and set the Style as `Global Override` and check the `Enable global font size` checkbox.

I've also attached a screenshot[image: link]

Answer (score 6):

This should [work](https://superuser.com/a/16834).

Settings > Style Configurator. Under Font Style you can set the font and size

Answer (score 1):

Font size is defined inside theme file:

> %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Notepad++\themes\Solarized (Light).xml

Open the file in editor and replace `fontSize="10"` with your value.
`fontSize="12"` is correct value on my screen.